# open and close curly bracket with condition in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array in php as given below:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 10
            [team2_score] => 5
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Chennai super kings
            [teamtitle2] => Spartans
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 15
            [team2_score] => 10
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Lions11
            [teamtitle2] => Kings Xl Punjab
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 15
            [team2_score] => 5
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Zimbabwe
            [teamtitle2] => Red Steel
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 10
            [team2_score] => 15
            [round_number] => 2
            [teamtitle1] => Zimbabwe
            [teamtitle2] => Chennai super kings
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 15
            [team2_score] => 7
            [round_number] => 3
            [teamtitle1] => Chennai super kings
            [teamtitle2] => Chennai super kings
        )

)
```

from this array i want json format array given below:-

```
[
                        [ {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "score" : 10 }, {"name" : "spartans",  "score" : 5} ],
                        [ {"name" : "Lions11", "score" : 15 }, {"name" : "Kings Xl Punjab",  "score" : 10} ],
                        [ {"name" : "Zimbabwe", "score" : 15 }, {"name" : "Red Steel",  "score" : 5} ],
                    ], 
                    [
                        [ {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "score" : 10 }, {"name" : "Zimbabwe",  "score" : 5} ],
                    ],
                    [
                        [ {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "score" : 10 }, {"name" : "Lions11",  "score" : 5} ],
                    ]
```

I've tried this but it is not coming in proper format. Please help me guys i got stuck in this. Any help will be appreciated Thanks in Advance

Comment: Uh... what? Could you please clarify?

Comment: himm maybe you should look at some `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` php's native functions. just saying.

Comment: You do know about `json_encode` right ?

Comment: Are you *hardcoding* json?

Comment: Dont hardcode JSON data. Build an Object or an Array of the size and shape you want the JSON data to look like. Then just use `json_encode()` to convert the object or array into a valid JSON data string

Comment: your codes are too complex , better to include desired output in question

Comment: i know json encode decode but i want to create my own json. And i just want to know that how to start and close square bracket in foreach if variable inside foreach changes. In my array there are 5 matches in which 1st round is having 3 matches second and third is having 1 match. So square bracket should open and close when there is round change

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense. Can you please post the desired JSON format so we can have an idea of what you want?

Comment: i'd updated the question guys

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: that i'd added in previous question now i can't edit in comment and show u. i'd foreach the array and generated json array

Answer (score 1):

First you need to modify your data structure so you have separate array for the team1 and team2 combination. Add that to one holding array and then just use `json_encode` simple as that.

```
// $data is your array
$output = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $output[] = [
        ['name'=>$row['teamtitle1'], 'score'=>$row['team1_score']], 
        ['name'=>$row['teamtitle2'], 'score'=>$row['team2_score']]
    ];
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Edit: As stated in the comments if you want to add another record all you have to do is obviously first find the winner and after that add it to the data set like this:

```
$output[] = ['name'=>'I am the Winner!', 'score'=>'99999'];
json_encode($output);
```

Comment: i dont want to use json encode because at the end of the loop i've to create one more json entry which contains the name of final match winner.

Comment: @ClememsWichmann appending to the `$output` array after the loop, before calling json_encode seems the way to do this. After all, a json array or object can be perfectly represented by a PHP array.

Comment: @ClememsWichmann I've added extra code, did you try that, did it work?